# How add new form in QT application

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I use Visual studio 2012, and add plugin for QT. How to add new form to main window? When i try to add new item, compiler don't generates code, when i click to .h file it says "the document cannot be opened. it has been renamed deleted or moved".

Thanks.

Comment: You can surely provide more details? With your reputation, you could even include screenshots, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the Visual Studio plugin installed and you add a new Qt form to the project, two new files are added to your project, a `xxx.ui` file under the `Form Files` folder and a `ui_xxx.h` under the `Generated Files` folder.

You will be allowed to edit the `xxx.ui` file by double-clicking on it and Qt Designer will open up.

The `ui_xxx.h` file will not initially be editable (not that you'd want to edit it anyway) because only a reference to it gets added in the project file, no physical file is created on the disk. The header file is only created when you execute your next build.

EDIT:
If you don't want to do a full build, you could also just right-click on your new `xxx.ui` file in the Solution Explorer and select `Compile` from the context menu. That will run uic to generate your header code.

Comment: Thanks for response, i have solved already, i needed this words "The header file is only created when you execute your next build.". I got error when try to open that file. Thank you :)